# build a dashboard and filter by account

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

How would I build a custom dashboard page (visualforce page) and use a customer account lookup on the page to filter it by. I would envisage having two graphs, one for list of opportunities and the other for list of cases. Could you supply link to sample code?

Comment: is there any specific reason to do this in visualforce ? did you try using standard reports & dashboards with dashboard filters to achieve this ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna the dashboard filter is limited to 10 items, I need to be able to select any account... unless you know something else??